# Prototype datepicker like Google Analytics

Tags: datepicker, prototypejs

I found [this Jquery based Datepicker](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker/) and like it, however my app is pretty entangled with Prototype and I'm getting errors

```
Error: TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
```

Rather than spend time getting Jquery to play nicely with Protptype, is there a good Prototype based datepicker similar to what Google Analytics uses (or the one linked above)?

Edit:
Following [these directions](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries), I added

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
             jQuery.noConflict()
         </script>
```

After both Prototype and JQuery libraries loaded.  I'm not getting any errors now, but the [datepicker](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker/) is nonfunctional.

Comment: if you want to use noConflict() you need to load the libraries in the right order jquery first, run `noConflict()` then load PrototypeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to migrate everything to jquery. Problem solved. :)